# Deserializing JToken content to an Object

Tags: c#, json, salesforce, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I want to deserialize JToken content to an object (`User`). How am I able to do this?

**Here is my json string:**

```
string json = @"[{""UserId"":0,""Username"":""jj.stranger"",""FirstName"":""JJ"",""LastName"":""stranger""}]";
```

This being sent to an api parameter as `JToken`.

**User class:**

```cs
public class user
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

**Web Api Method:**

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]JToken users)
{
      UserModel.SaveUser(users);
      //...
}
```

**API Invocation in Salesforce:**

```
string json = '[{"UserId":0,"Username":"jj.stranger","FirstName":"JJ","LastName":"stranger"}]';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();
            
req.setEndpoint('test.com/api/UserManagement');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(json);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            
try {
    res = http.send(req);
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    System.debug('Callout error:' + e);
}
            
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use JToken.ToObject generic method.
    http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json/JToken/M/ToObject(T)

Server API Code:

```
 public void Test(JToken users)
 {
     var usersArray = users.ToObject<User[]>();
 }
```

Here is the client code I use.

```
string json = "[{\"UserId\":0,\"Username\":\"jj.stranger\",\"FirstName\":\"JJ\",\"LastName\":\"stranger\"}]";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = client.PostAsync(@"http://localhost:50577/api/values/test", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

The object gets converted to Users array without any issues.

Comment: I used that, something like this `List<User> userList = users.ToObject<List<User>>();` however it gives me an error, `Error converting value `.

Comment: Can you try users.ToObject<User[]>(). I think JSON.net treats the object as an array. Meanwhile I will try to replicate this in my machine.

Comment: I tried it now and it works. How are you invoking the API? Can you share the code you use for invocation?

Comment: see my updated question. However I'm not testing it by calling the API, I created a console project to test the `deserialization`.

Comment: which one did you try the `List` or as `Array`?

Comment: I tried the Array version. I did the testing using Fiddler.

Comment: could you try the `List`, it really gives me an error.

Comment: It would make any difference If test this in the console project that I created right? hmm, but I will try it in invoking the api.

Comment: No, a different client should not make any difference. I have updated the answer with the client and server code I used for testing.

Comment: this is funny, it's working in api invocation. :D thanks for the effort @Sarathy

Comment: This works fine, but it simply ignores data fields which cannot be mapped to the target class. Is there a way to get errors for that (appreciated with field name)?

Comment: I have not tried this yet. But there is an overload for the method ToObject<T>() which accepts an instance of JsonSerializer. You can try to create an instance of JsonSerializer and set the value of MissingMemberHandling to Error. But this will throw a  JsonSerializationException  as per the documentation.

Comment: ToObject will create new instance and will throw exception for abstract class or interface it's better to convert it using the type 
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myjson.ToString(Formatting.None), ChildClassType) as BaseClassType;

Answer (score 1):

--This worked for me, the Json is super huge +111000 lines---

```
//String of keys to search deepin the Json for the desired objects
public string sTokenKeys = "results.drug.drugsfda.partitions";

//Read the download.json file into its objects.                
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JsonFileLocation);
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
var data = JObject.Parse(json);   //Get a JObject from the Json
// Find the desired tree branch by the token keys
var partitionsJObject = data.SelectToken(sTokenKeys).ToList();
// get the array of JTokens and serialize-deserialize into 
// appropriate object 
var partitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Partition>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(partitionsJObject));

//now i can read the List<Partition>> partitions object for the 
// values im looking for
```