# Deserialize Open Street Map JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, openstreetmap, json-deserialization

If I have this JSON where there is a header with the tags `version`, `generator`, `om3s` and `elements`.  `elements` can be of type `node` or `way` and the associated JSON keys vary based on type.  I am trying to use [JsonSubTypes](https://manuc66.github.io/JsonSubTypes/) to convert each element type to a C# class.

Example JSON:

```
[
  {
    "version": 0.6,
    "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.7 8b86ff77",
    "osm3s": {
      "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-05-21T18:03:02Z",
      "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
    },
    "elements": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "id": 4949106384,
        "lat": 32.2686857,
        "lon": -107.738218,
        "tags": {
          "highway": "turning_circle"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "way",
        "id": 14527404,
        "nodes": [
          142882281,
          3048075541,
          1598998260
        ],
        "tags": {
          "highway": "residential",
          "name": "West Apple Street",
          "tiger:cfcc": "A41",
          "tiger:county": "Luna, NM",
          "tiger:name_base": "Apple",
          "tiger:name_direction_prefix": "W",
          "tiger:name_type": "St",
          "tiger:reviewed": "no"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to deserialize it using:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OSMdata>(jsonText);
```

Where `OSMdata` looks like:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "type")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Element.Node), "node")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Element.Edge), "way")]

public abstract class OSMdata
{
    public float version { get; set; }
    public string generator { get; set; }
    public Osm3s osm3s { get; set; }
    public Element[] elements { get; set; }
}

public class Osm3s : OSMdata
{
    public DateTime timestamp_osm_base { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
}

public class Element : OSMdata
{
    public class Node : Element
    {
        public string type { get; } = "node";
        public long id { get; set; }
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lon { get; set; }
        public NodeTags tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class NodeTags : Node
    {
        public string highway { get; set; }
        public string _ref { get; set; }
    }

    public class Edge : Element
    {
        public string type { get; } = "way";
        public long id { get; set; }
        public long[] nodes { get; set; }
        public EdgeTags tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class EdgeTags : Edge
    {
        public string highway { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string cfcc { get; set; }
        public string county { get; set; }
        public string oneway { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
   at JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.CreateCompatibleList(Type targetContainerType, Type elementType)
   at JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.ReadArray(JsonReader reader, Type targetType, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at newapp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\RDCRLDDH\source\repos\newapp\newapp\Program.cs:line 23
```

While I don't understand this error and am looking for a solution, here are a few questions I would like clarity on:

### Questions

Am I properly constructing the class `OSMdata`?  I think I am following the examples correctly, but am not sure if I am properly assigning the classes `Node` and `Edge` to the parent class `OSMdata`.

How will the deserializer know to assign the tag `"tiger:cfcc"` to the `Cfcc` property in `EdgeTags`?

Comment: An alternative solution is to add a `NodeOrEdge` class and write custom cast between them. Let the library handles the missing keys.

Comment: Rather than loading to some huge `dynamic` object then manually deserializing, you can deserialize to model with a polymorphic `element` array.  For how see [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182), [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) or [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the reading!

Comment: Anytime you use `dynamic` always think to your self the is most likely a better way

Comment: @dubbbdan - you're welcome.  Did those answer your question?  If not you can always use `JToken.ToObject<NodeTags>()` or  `JToken.ToObject<Edge>()` as shown in [Deserializing JToken content to an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28492098/344280/) and [Converting a JToken (or string) to a given Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407670/344280).  Hopefully your question gets answered by one of these other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to deserialize directly from the JSON, but found a suitable workaround that converts the JSON to `JArray` and iterates though each element and converting to a C# class that is composed of nodes and edges.

Using the class `Element`:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "type")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Element.Node), "node")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Element.Edge), "way")]

    public class Element
    {
        public class Node : Element

        {
            public string type { get; } = "node";
            public long id { get; set; }
            public float lat { get; set; }
            public float lon { get; set; }
            public NodeTags tags { get; set; }
        }

    public class NodeTags : Node
    {
        public string highway { get; set; }
        public string _ref { get; set; }
    }

    public class Edge : Element
    {
        public string type { get; } = "way";
        public long id { get; set; }
        public long[] nodes { get; set; }
        public EdgeTags tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class EdgeTags : Edge
    {
        [JsonProperty("highway")]
        public string Highway { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("tiger:cfcc")]
        public string cfcc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tiger:county")]
        public string County { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("oneway")]
        public string Oneway { get; set; }
    }
```

You can parse thje json using:

```
JArray jsonSearch = JArray.Parse(jsonText);
```

You can then create a list consisting of each element using:

```
IList<JToken> results = jsonSearch[0]["elements"].Children().ToList();
```

Then you can iterate through `results` and convert the data to C# objects using:

```
var element_list = new List<Element>();

foreach (JObject element in results)
{
    Element myelement = element.ToObject<Element>();
    element_list.Add(myelement);
}
```

Of the questions I posed, the second is still relevant.

You can assign a property with an invalid name to a C# class using `JsonProperty` before you create the property name within the class.

```
[JsonProperty("tiger:cfcc")]
public string cfcc { get; set; }
```

Thanks @dbc and other helpful comments for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Declare your classes as follows:

```cs
    // no longer abstract
    public class OSMdata
    {
        public float version { get; set; }
        public string generator { get; set; }
        public Osm3s osm3s { get; set; }

        // for arrays or collection this line must be present here
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "type")]
        public Element[] elements { get; set; }
    }

    // no need to inherits from OSMData
    public class Osm3s
    {
        public DateTime timestamp_osm_base { get; set; }
        public string copyright { get; set; }
    }


    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "type")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Node), "node")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Edge), "way")]
    public abstract class Element : OSMdata
    {
        public abstract string type { get; }
    }

    public class Node : Element
    {
        public override string type { get; } = "node";
        public long id { get; set; }
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lon { get; set; }
        public NodeTags tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class NodeTags
    {
        public string highway { get; set; }
        public string _ref { get; set; }
    }

    public class Edge : Element
    {
        public override string type { get; } = "way";
        public long id { get; set; }
        public long[] nodes { get; set; }
        public EdgeTags tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class EdgeTags
    {
        public string highway { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string cfcc { get; set; }
        public string county { get; set; }
        public string oneway { get; set; }
    }
```

and deserialize with:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OSMdata>(jsonText);
```

see running sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdJ0ab

Comment: Would it be appropriate to associate `EdgeTags` with `Edge` (i.e. `public class EdgeTags : Edge`)?